# what's the correct way to write this code

Tags: php, joomla

I have a code to show  fields from the database. I can get it normally to show up within my joomla framework. But to perform correct links

i need to use this code

```
 <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=time&view=one&id='.$url.'&layout=common'); ?>">


 echo "<td> that code would be here
```

Cant do a echo within that echo

```
 echo "<td><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=time&view=one&id='.$url.'&layout=common'); ?>">mylink</a></td>
```

that would not work  what would be the correct way

Comment: in the second echo i cant echo within that echo what would be the correct way to echo that statement within the <td>

Answer (score 2):

Why are you adding the PHP tags inside of the echo? There's no need for them, you're already inside the PHP tags since you're using echo.

```
echo "<td><a href='" . JRoute::_('index.php?option=time&view=one&id='.$url.'&layout=common') . "'>mylink</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  echo '<td><a href="' . JRoute::_( . 'index.php?option=time&view=one&id=' . $url . '&layout=common' . ) . '">mylink</a></td>';
```

Alteratively try the below

```
  ?>
  <td><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=time&view=one&id=' . $url . '&layout=common'); ?>">mylink</a></td>;
  <?php
```

Comment: tried all three and none of them worked they give me a syntax error on a blank line